# Grails 4 Spring Security Plugin

Tags: gradle, grails, spring-security, grails-4

After upgrading from Grails 3.3.9 to 4 there are several packages missing. E.g. `unable to resolve class org.springframework.security.provisioning.JdbcUserDetailsManager`. Has anyone any ideas? I've done all the steps from here: https://docs.grails.org/4.0.0.M1/guide/upgrading.html.
It seems that Gradle 5 can not load all the dependencies in the plugin. With Grails 3.3.9 and Gradle Wrapper 3.5 everything worked fine.
Thanks for any advices.

Comment: I'd imagine, that many plugins won't work without migration.  Most of the underlyting spring libs had major version jumps.

Comment: @cfrick Spring-security-core 4 M1 is for Grails 4. Many plugins I've tested did not need migration (some did of course).

Comment: Please check https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/11154